# What type should an ink! contract use to store a `uint256` block number retrieved from a Solidity contract?

Tags: ink, cross-contract-call, blocknumber

In Solidity, if we get the `block.number` it returns type `uint256` (alias `uint`), so I use type `uint256` to store the block number in a Solidity contract.

However, in ink! the equivalent `u256` is not allowed (as mentioned [here](https://use.ink/ink-vs-solidity#uint256)), as only up to `u128` is supported, and they suggest alternatives like using a wrapper around `[u64; 4]`.

Based on [this question](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/9140/usage-of-xvm-in-ink-smart-contract) it appears that ink! **cross-chain** contract calls using XVM and XCM as it is not yet supported, however in [the answer to this question](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/8721/how-to-interact-between-a-smart-contract-written-in-solidity-from-a-smart-contra/8723#8723) they highlight it is possible to do **cross-contract** calls into a Solidity contract from an ink! contract and vice versa from an ink! contract to a Solidity contract too on the same chain.

So if we made a **cross-contract** call on the same chain from an ink! contract to a function in a Solidity contract that fetched and returned the latest block number of type `uint256` value, what type should we store that as in the ink! contract where it gets returned to?

Note that when dealing with Substrate-based chains we use `u32` as shown [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/bin/node/primitives/src/lib.rs#L30).

Comment: To my knowledge there is still no working version of XVM.
Why don't use `[u8; 32]` for u256, and impl `From` for your needs?
In a similar manner, the EVM type `address` in Astar XVM is actually `[u8; 20]` which is equivalent for H160

Comment: @PierreOssun mentioned that this shows how to decode in ink! a call to a getter in Solidity https://github.com/AstarNetwork/ink-xvm-sdk/blob/18944607edb83a61e9a016eb588c5ee0804f2c70/contracts/erc20/lib.rs#L53

Answer (score 4):

In ink! you can use `self.env().block_number()` or `Self::env().block_number()` in the constructor.

If you want to use XVM (only available in Shibuya) and query an solidity contract, you can deploy a solidity contract that returns the block number and call it like this:

```
            // get selector of the function from metadata
            const SELECTOR: [u8; 4] = hex!["18160ddd"];

            let mut encoded = SELECTOR.to_vec();
            let input = [];
            encoded.extend(&ethabi::encode(&input));

            let result = self.env().extension().xvm_call(
                super::EVM_ID,
                Vec::from(self.evm_address.as_ref()),
                encoded,
            );

            ink::env::debug_println!("xvm_call result: {:?}", result);

            if let Ok([Token::Uint(int)]) = ethabi::decode(
                &[ethabi::ParamType::Uint(256)],
                &result.expect("xvm_call failed"),
            )
            .as_deref()
            {
                int.as_u128()
            } else {
                panic!("failed to decode xvm_call result")
            }
```

Source:
https://github.com/AstarNetwork/ink-xvm-sdk/blob/18944607edb83a61e9a016eb588c5ee0804f2c70/contracts/erc20/lib.rs#L53